# How can I copy the URL of a question on the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, questions, android-app

How can I copy the question URL to the clipboard on Android?

Comment: Why did you tag this as a bug?  Do you think it is a bug?  Or are you trying to learn how to do it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry I edited question.

Comment: Since the bug tag was incorrect (which is why I was trying to clarify), I changed it to a support question for you.  If you find out that the feature does not exist, then you can propose a feature request.  But if you do propose one, I would suggest you do it over on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) as the app developers prefer app questions on that site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 OK, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Google Drive installed, then you can click Share on the post in SE app, and choose Copy to Clipboard. It will copy the URL of the post.

Comment: I can't find a share button for the post.

Comment: It should be above the user information box on the bottom. (in fact, I'm answering this from the app, so I'm certain)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer